# how to boost the loading process of an iOS project in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When i open a relative big iOS project in Xcode 8, it almost last more then 5 minutes. It last so long time in loading process. I have tried to restart the Mac and clean the DerivedData, but it isn't useful. Could anyone help me boost the opening process in Xcode. The code is wrote in Objective-C.

By the way, this Xcode is often crashed when i close this project...

Comment: no other way except upgrade your mac.

Comment: You can upgrade your mac. Other things you can do is make sure you're running the latest version of XCode /  macOS.

Comment: i don't think it is the hardware problem, i got this new rmbp 5 month ago...

Answer (score 0):

(i)check free space
 (ii) RAM of system
(iii) delete previous Archives
if everything is fine, xcode is going to corrupt. reinstall from another xip

Answer (score 0):

Please try to upgrade your **Mac** and **Xcode** to latest version. I hope, it solve your problem.

Comment: both the system and the Xcode is the latest version 0.0